# Song played at the end of episode 20 of Parasyte

Tags: music, parasyte

Does anyone know the suspense build-up song being played at the end of episode 20 when the military enters the courtroom? Thanks!

Comment: Do you maybe have a time stamp to go along with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song is called "HYPNOTIK" by Ken Arai.

You can listen to the song [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HUwGFVeN04). In addition to being played at the end of episode 20, it's also played throughout the show in other episodes.